# Python error 'int' object has no attribute 'penup' (python turtle)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am playing around with the turtle function in python that I am very new to. I have imported turtle and created the screen, and all I am trying to do is make him jump to another coordinate but every time I call this function I get an error. Probably an easy and obvious fix, but heres what I have:

```
    import turtle
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    t=turtle.Turtle()

    def jump(t, x, y):
       #makes turtle t jump to coordinates (x, y)
       t.penup()
       t.goto(x, y)
       t.pendown()
```

And this is the error:

```
         AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'penup'
```

Comment: How do you call jump? `t` is an int, not a Turtle (due to duck-typing python only notices it when you call a wrong method).

Comment: I figured it out, I was calling it wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of turtle to your jump()-Funktion. My example code works (though it makes no sense):

```
import turtle

def jump(t, x, y):
   #makes turtle t jump to coordinates (x, y)
   t.penup()
   t.goto(x, y)
   t.pendown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    jump(t, 0, 0)
```